# How to pad numbers to the border of the Matrix?

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

I want to pad the numbers,but it throws an error `Part::partw`,so I use `Quiet` to suppress this error.

```
lis = {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7, 8}, {9, 10, 11, 12}, {13, 14, 15, 16}};

n = 6;(*It can change be any size bigger than Dimensions[lis]*)
sum = ConstantArray[0, {n, n}];

Quiet@Do[sum[[x, y]] = 
lis[[Floor[x/2] + 1, Floor[y/2] + 1]] + 
lis[[Floor[x/2] + 2, Floor[y/2] + 1]] + 
lis[[Floor[x/2] + 1, Floor[y/2] + 2]] + 
lis[[Floor[x/2] + 2, Floor[y/2] + 2]], {x, n}, {y, n}]

mat1=Replace[sum, _Plus -> "Error", {2}]
```

$\left(
\begin{array}{cccccc}
 14 & 18 & 18 & 22 & 22 & \text{Error} \\
 30 & 34 & 34 & 38 & 38 & \text{Error} \\
 30 & 34 & 34 & 38 & 38 & \text{Error} \\
 46 & 50 & 50 & 54 & 54 & \text{Error} \\
 46 & 50 & 50 & 54 & 54 & \text{Error} \\
 \text{Error} & \text{Error} & \text{Error} & \text{Error} & \text{Error} & \text{Error} \\
\end{array}
\right)$

But I expect the output would be:

```
mat2={{14, 18, 18, 22, 22, 22}, {30, 34, 34, 38, 38, 38}, {30, 34, 34, 38, 38, 38}, {46, 50, 50, 54, 54, 54}, {46, 50, 50, 54, 54, 54}, {46, 50, 50, 54, 54, 54}};
```

$\left(
\begin{array}{cccccc}
 14 & 18 & 18 & 22 & 22 & 22 \\
 30 & 34 & 34 & 38 & 38 & 38 \\
 30 & 34 & 34 & 38 & 38 & 38 \\
 46 & 50 & 50 & 54 & 54 & 54 \\
 46 & 50 & 50 & 54 & 54 & 54 \\
 46 & 50 & 50 & 54 & 54 & 54 \\
\end{array}
\right)$

How to implement this in *Mathematica*?
Or how about this:How to transform the `mat1` to `mat2`?

Comment: So when `n` is larger, say when `n=7`, what will the extra rows and columns of the output be?  Will they just be copies of the final rows and columns again?

Comment: Yes,they just be copies of the final rows and columns again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you can't ask for more elements of the list than it has, so you can't have the iterators `x` and `y` go higher than 5 in your code.  Then you can just use `ArrayPad` to do the padding:

```
lis = {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7, 8}, {9, 10, 11, 12}, {13, 14, 15, 16}};

n = 6;
sum = ConstantArray[0, {5, 5}];

Do[sum[[x, y]] = 
  lis[[Floor[x/2] + 1, Floor[y/2] + 1]] + 
   lis[[Floor[x/2] + 2, Floor[y/2] + 1]] + 
   lis[[Floor[x/2] + 1, Floor[y/2] + 2]] + 
   lis[[Floor[x/2] + 2, Floor[y/2] + 2]], {x, 5}, {y, 5}]
ArrayPad[sum, {0, n - 5}, "Fixed"] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

But I would rewrite the `Do` loop as a `Table`,

```
n = 12;
mat1 = ArrayPad[
   Table[
    Total[
     lis[[Floor[x/2] + 1 ;; Floor[x/2] + 2,
       Floor[y/2] + 1 ;; Floor[y/2] + 2]],
     2],
    {x, 5}, {y, 5}],
   {0, n - 5}, "Fixed"];
mat1 // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you,I know how to handle this problem now:)

Comment: @partida, glad to help.  I was generally confused by the particular matrix you are using here, but I think the general answer to the question of how to pad a matrix on the right and bottom with extra copies of the final row and column is `ArrayPad[  matrix, {0, X}, "Fixed"]` where `X` is the number of extra rows to pad

Comment: yeah,ArrayPad is the key to my problem,and I hasn't noticed at the beginning

Comment: If not for the repeated elements, `Partition[]` would have done nicely: `Map[Total[#, 2] &, Partition[lis, {2, 2}, {1, 1}], {2}]`. `Take[]` works fine, tho: `Table[Total[Take[lis, Quotient[j, 2] + {1, 2}, Quotient[k, 2] + {1, 2}], 2], {j,   5}, {k, 5}]`